# What to make out of the output of QSG_RENDERER_DEBUG=render

Tags: qml, render, qtquick2

When I set the environment variable `QSG_RENDERER_DEBUG=render` , I get the following output:

```
Renderer::render() QSGAbstractRenderer(0x383865f8) "rebuild: none"
Rendering:
 -> Opaque: 38 nodes in 2 batches...
 -> Alpha: 34 nodes in 13 batches...
 - 0x3836a830 [retained] [noclip] [opaque] [  merged]  Nodes:   14  Vertices:    88  Indices:   124  root: 0x0
 - 0x3836a7f0 [  upload] [noclip] [opaque] [  merged]  Nodes:   24  Vertices:    96  Indices:   144  root: 0x0
 - 0x3836a8f0 [retained] [noclip] [ alpha] [unmerged]  Nodes:    1  Vertices:    48  Indices:    74  root: 0x0
 - 0x3836a870 [retained] [noclip] [ alpha] [unmerged]  Nodes:    3  Vertices:    52  Indices:    78  root: 0x0
 - 0x3836a8b0 [retained] [noclip] [ alpha] [unmerged]  Nodes:    6  Vertices:   400  Indices:   720  root: 0x0
 - 0x3836a530 [retained] [noclip] [ alpha] [unmerged]  Nodes:    4  Vertices:    56  Indices:    84  root: 0x0
 - 0x3836a570 [retained] [noclip] [ alpha] [  merged]  Nodes:    1  Vertices:     4  Indices:     6  root: 0x0 opacity: 1
 - 0x3836a5b0 [retained] [noclip] [ alpha] [unmerged]  Nodes:    7  Vertices:   720  Indices:  1302  root: 0x0
 - 0x3836a630 [retained] [noclip] [ alpha] [unmerged]  Nodes:    3  Vertices:    28  Indices:    42  root: 0x0
 - 0x3836a5f0 [retained] [noclip] [ alpha] [  merged]  Nodes:    3  Vertices:    12  Indices:    18  root: 0x0 opacity: 1
 - 0x3836a6f0 [retained] [noclip] [ alpha] [  merged]  Nodes:    1  Vertices:     4  Indices:     6  root: 0x0 opacity: 1
 - 0x3836a670 [retained] [noclip] [ alpha] [  merged]  Nodes:    1  Vertices:     4  Indices:     6  root: 0x0 opacity: 1
 - 0x3836a6b0 [retained] [noclip] [ alpha] [  merged]  Nodes:    1  Vertices:     4  Indices:     6  root: 0x0 opacity: 1
 - 0x3836a330 [retained] [noclip] [ alpha] [unmerged]  Nodes:    2  Vertices:    24  Indices:    36  root: 0x0
 - 0x3836a370 [retained] [noclip] [ alpha] [  merged]  Nodes:    1  Vertices:     4  Indices:     6  root: 0x0 opacity: 1
 -> times: build: 0, prepare(opaque/alpha): 0/0, sorting: 0, upload(opaque/alpha): 0/0, render: 1
```

which I deem bad to catastrophal, if I want to run it on a low-performance-device such as an old Raspberry PI.

However I fail to find the answers to: **what to make out of this? How can I improve it, to reduce the amount of batches, especially the Alpha-batches?**

I have only few objects (2) with `opacity != 0` and at the time of this output all of them have been set to invisible.

I have two SVGs (8 nodes each) which might show up there.

I do not use any colors that would not fit in the format `'#------ff'` (unless the svg-colors of which I use a few might have the alpha-channel set otherwise) and do not use the color `'transparent'`

I do have an object that consists out of two "concentric" `Rectangles` of opaque color, that are marked *unmerged* when visualizing the *overdraw*, which I have no clue, why. At least it could be merged with it's not-intersecting siblings, I deem. **Why wouldn't they?**

I think it migh help if I might identify the objects, but when I ouput the adresses of any object that is visible, (`Component.onCompleted: console.log(this)`) I do not get any of the listed adresses.
**How might I achieve a mapping between the render-objects and my QML-Objects?**

And - **What doe all those list entries mean at all?**

**EDIT:** It seems, I used some PNG's with alpha enabled. Replacing them with JPG reduced the message to this. But those were only 5 of the nodes/batches. 34 to go...

```
 -> Opaque: 43 nodes in 6 batches...
 -> Alpha: 29 nodes in 8 batches...
```

Greetings & Thanks,
-m-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [doc.qt.io](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-visualcanvas-scenegraph-renderer.html#transform-nodes): "[one batch] is created for each unique set of material state and geometry type". Reduce the number of differences and the default renderer puts compatible OpenGL primitives into the same batch.

For example:

- Rectangle elements with different `width`/`height`/`color`/`gradient`/`rotation` properties are batched together but with different `opacity`/`radius`/`antialiasing` properties are not.
- Rectangle elements with the `color` property set to an opaque value using hexadecimal triplets (Ex.: specifying `'forestgreen'` with `'#228B22'` or `'#282'`) are batched together. But specifying translucent colors (a hex quad that does not start with `'#FF`', ex.: `'#44228B22'` -- 25% opaque `'forestgreen'`) forces a separate batch *even if the translucent color values are identical* (verified on Qt 5.9.1). Having translucent `border` colors also forces separate batches *even if the translucent color values are identical*.
- Text elements with different `font` `letterspacing`/`underline`
  properties are grouped together, but different `font` `bold`/`italic`/`pixelSize`/`hintingPreference` properties are separated.

You can determine which objects are which by changing the visible property and seeing what appears or disappears.